# Is CV's 'Reopen votes' review queue working right now?

Tags: bug

A few minutes ago I had to `skip` the two reopen votes visible in my review queue because I couldn't complete any of them due to a strange error of the kind

> An error occurred bla bla bla...

I also see that there were no reopen votes reviewed so far which is quite strange...

Comment: This is a perfectly valid question to ask, but the best place to get an answer is on the network wide main Meta site. As elected moderators or high-rep users, we don't have any insight into the site's software or infrastructure.

Comment: Thank you @Sycorax-OnStrike. I want to make sure this is happening to others as well.

Comment: Temporary glitches like this happen all the time.  (I experienced this one about an hour ago, too.)  Unless *nothing* works (check one of the status sites for that, such as https://www.stackstatus.net/), then just move on to something else and return to your activity in an hour or two.  BTW, the queue appears to be working again.

Comment: Yeah, I see the reviews now. Thank you both!

Comment: Two issues I have encountered yesterday: the   along side the reopen votes to which checking showed there was only one post to be reviewed (and it still happened now) and even after clearing the queue, the  is still there and secondly there was this single review which I tried few times only to be receiving an error message (finally I skipped that). Re the former, it happened few months ago in low quality queue, iirc

Comment: And it's still [there](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0oReA.jpg).

Comment: Hi @User1865345-solidarityMods. Yep, I'm having the same issue, again...

Comment: I guess it's over now.

Comment: @User1865345, Yep it's working again.

Comment: It never ceases to amuse me. It's back.

Comment: @User1865345 didn't have time to review this morning but it's working now.

Comment: Ah yes! It is normal again. I would stop reporting this self-repairing issue. :-)